# Removing a space, newline, and tabs with string trimming in C

Tags: c, string, error-handling, while-loop, trim

I was trying to gather sources from the internet to understand how it works and functions. Basically, I will need to check a space, newline, and tabs every time that it reads a string. So I made a function that takes care of that case:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static int  isspace(char c)
{
    return (c == '\t' || c == '\n' || c == ' ');
}
```

Then, I use the function below to implement it in ANOTHER function

```
char *my_strtrim(char const *string)
{
    char *i;
    char *s;
    int ready;

    i = s;
    s = (char *)string;
    ready = 0;
    while(*i)
    {
        ++i;
        if(isspace(*i))
        {
            if(!ready)
            {
                continue ;
            }
            ready = 0;
        }
        ready = 1;
        *(s++) = *i;
    }

    *s = 0;
    return ((char *)string);
}
```

For my main, I just made a random test case where it takes care of spaces, tabs, and newline:

```
int main()
{
    char str[] = "                      hello world\n !";
    printf("%s",my_strtrim(str));
}
```

There is an output error that there an error in my_strtrim function with `i = s` because `s` is has no result of `NULL`. The error says:

```
my_strtrim.c: error: variable 's' is uninitialized when used here [-Werror,-Wuninitialized]
        i = s;
            ^
my_strtrim.c: note: initialize the variable 's' to silence this warning
        char *s;
               ^
                = NULL
```

After I fix what it says (making `s = NULL`) I get a segmentation fault. This problem has become confusing because it works fine as a for-loop, but not as a while loop. I am required to do this problem as a while-loop.

**SOLUTION**
My friend gave me a little tip/rule of thumb, which is keeping code simple and nice to understand. I had a single cluster function doing a lot of things in the same; therefore, I was getting confused. He guided me and told me to make me to condense my whole function into little pieces.

## STEP 0: Initilize variables and declare

 
Self explanatory

**STEP 1: GET POSITION OF YOUR POINTER STRING**

```
int     step1_getPosition(char const *string)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while(my_iswhitespace(string[i]))
    {
            i++;
            continue;
    }
    return (i);
}
```

## STEP 2: COPY YOUR STRING

```
char    *step2_copyString(char const *string, int pos)
{
    char *tmp;
    int     i;

    i = 0;
    tmp = my_strnew(my_strlen(string));
    if(tmp == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    while (string[pos] != '\0')
        tmp[i++] = string[pos++];
    return (tmp);
}
```

## STEP 3: REMOVE WHITE SPACES

```
char    *step3_removeWhite(char *str)
{
    int i;

    i = my_strlen(str);
    while (str[i] == '\0' || my_iswhitespace(str[i]))
    {
        str[i] = '\0';
        i--;
    }
    return (str);
}
```

## STEP 4: REMOVE EXTRA NULL-BYTES ('\0')

```
char    *step4_removeExtraNulls(char *str)
{
    char *newstring;

    newstring = my_strdup(str);
    if(newstring == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    free(str);
    return (newstring);
}
```

## STEP 5: MAIN FUNCTION CALLED WITH THE OTHER FUNCTIONS CREATED

```
char    *my_strtrim(char const *string)
{
    char    *trim;
    int     i;

    i = step1_getPosition(string);
    trim = step2_copyString(string, i);
    if (trim == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    step3_removeWhite(trim);
    trim = step4_removeExtraNulls(trim);
    if (trim == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    return (trim);
}
```

The output I get is:
`hello world`
`!`
Which this is correct

Comment: Why not use the *standard* [`isspace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace) function?

Comment: By the way, you have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as you modify a string which is `const`. If you want to modify the contents of `string` the *don't* mark it as `const`.

Comment: As for your erorr, think a little bit about the *order* in which you do things. When you do `i = s`, where does `s` point?

Comment: Lastly, I recommend you think a little bit more about what you're doing. What do you think happens when your function returns the *unmodified* variable `string`? Where does `string` point?

Comment: I had to recreate the `isspace` function because we are not allowed any of the C library (unless we make it by our own). I need to make my_strtrim as this kind of prototype:
`char *my_strtrim(char const *s)`
For your third comment, s would be pointing to nothing because is not declared. And for your fourth, is my string pointing to nothing then?

Comment: Yes when you do `i = s` the variable `s` is not pointing anywhere special, so where do you think `i` will point after that assignment? Again, think about the *order* you do things in. As for `string`, since you don't modify where `string` point, it will still point to the same location as when the function was called, which is the very first space. Then you return that pointer, which will of course lead you to print the full string with *all* the leading spaces.

Comment: And if you're required to receive the argument (`string` in your case) as a pointer to *constant* characters, you should not modify the characters!

Comment: And to "trim" leading space is very simple, just return a pointer to the first non-space character from your function. That's it. You can do this with a very simple loop that iterates as long as `*string` is a space (and not the terminator of course). No need for any other variables, that simple loop, that increases where `string` point (like `++string`) is all you really need.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, might as well go ahead and write it up as an answer and move another unanswered question off the books....

Comment: @ZeidTisnes Are you attempting to remove ALL whitespace (e.g. `"helloworld!"`), or just EXCESS whitespace leaving a single space between words? (in your example leaving `"hello world!"`)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I am removing the whitespaces from the beginning and the end only. I found the solution and I will share it now after I finish editing.

Comment: @ZeidTisnes - glad you got it working. Now that I know what you are attempting to do, I'll drop an answer showing you how you can tweak the end to remove the final whitespace between the `!` and `world`.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to "trim" leading white-space characters, is to just skip over them, not to modify the string at all.

This relies on the fact that a "string" in C can be expressed as a pointer to a sequence of null-terminated characters.

Take for example your string

```
char str[] = "                      hello world\n !";
```

If we let the array `str` decay to a pointer to its first element, it points to the first space. What if we had a pointer that pointed to the `'h'` instead? That would be an equally valid "string".

To get that pointer, we just loop over the string, as long as the current character is a space (and not the terminator of course).

Putting this into practice we get

```
char *my_strtrim(char const *string)
{
    for (/* empty */; *string && my_isspace(*string); ++string)
    {
        // Empty
    }

    return string;
}
```

After the loop in the function above, the pointer `string` will point *either* to the terminator (if the string was just all space), or to the first non-space character in the string.

If we use it like

```
printf("%s\n", my_strtrim(str));
```

then it will print

```
hello world
 !
```

<sub>[The embedded newline is because you have it in your string.]</sub>

It should be noted that this doesn't trim *trailing* spaces. For that to be possible, the argument `string` can't be a pointer to *constant* characters.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is happening because when yo're assigning the `i = s` the `s` variable is in an undefined condition.

Please, consider the below code:

```
char *my_strtrim(char const *string)
{
    char *i;
    char *s;
    int ready;

    s = (char *)string;
    i = s;
    ready = 0;
    while(*i)
    {
        ++i;
        if(isspace(*i))
        {
            if(!ready)
            {
                continue ;
            }
            ready = 0;
        }
        ready = 1;
        *(s++) = *i;
    }

    *s = 0;
    return ((char *)string);
}
```

Comment: `*s = '\0'` and `*s = 0` are 100% equivalent. The ASCII *nul-character* `'\0'` has decimal value `0`. (just as `'A'` has decimal value `65`, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Zeid, continuing from the comments. One of the efficiency goals should be to limit the number of passes you make over the string (optimally to one). You should also consider passing a final array to hold the trimmed string, as there are many instances where the original will need to be preserved, or, as correctly noted by Some programmer dude, you cannot modify and parameter specified as `const` or one that resides in *read only memory* (such as a *string literal*).

You can use a VLA for that purpose in the caller. Putting that altogether and adding an additional parameter to hold the result, `'r'` below, you could do something like the following.

It simply removes all leading whitespace, then backs up, removing all trailing whitespace, and checks whether the final character is anything other than an `alnum` character (since most sentences end with some type of punctuation). It then checks whether there is any additional whitespace between the punctuation and the last alnum char in the string removing any intervening whitespace by shuffling the end characters forward to overwrite any intervening whitespace found (this will get rid of your extra `'\n '` between `world` and `'!'`)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/** remove leading and trailing whitespace, original is preserved.
 *  this funciton can be used with or without assigning return.
 *  any intervening whitespace between end punctuation and first
 *  alpha-num character is also removed.
 */
char *strtrimws (char *r, const char *s)
{
    char *p = r;                            /* pointer to result         */
    *r = 0;                                 /* initialize as empty str   */
    if (!s) return NULL;                    /* validaate source str      */
    if (!*s) return r;                      /* empty str - nothing to do */
    while (isspace (*s))  s++;              /* skip leading whitespace   */
    while (*s) *p++ = *s++;                 /* fill r with s to end      */
    *p = 0;                                 /* nul-terminate r           */
    while (p > r && isspace (*--p)) *p = 0; /* overwrite spaces from end */
    while (p > r && !isalnum (*--p)) {      /* continue until 1st alnum  */
        if (isspace (*p)) {                 /* if spaces found           */
            char *rp = p, *wp = p;          /* set read & write pointers */
            while (*rp++) *wp++ = *rp;      /* shuffle end chars forward */
            *wp = 0;                        /* nul-terminate at new end  */
        }
    }
    return r;
}

int main (void) {

    char str[] = "                      hello world\n !",
        result[sizeof str];
    printf ("%s\n", strtrimws (result, str));
    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/trimws
hello world!
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any further questions. If not, good luck with your coding.